# Change class with javascript for row when number of rows is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function

I want to have a 'popup' div whenever I click on a row. I tried to do this with javascript to toggle a class. 
We are filling a table with WordPress custom post types and the number of rows are therefor unknown.

The id "bedrijfsinfo-x" is being generated correctly, and function counts the right amount of rows. It still toggles the class on all divs instead of just the one associated with the row I clicked on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php $counter = 1 ; ?>
    <?php
        // Als er berichten zijn gevonden.
        if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
            // While loop om alle berichten op te halen
            while ( $posts->have_posts() ) :
                $posts->the_post();
                global $post;
                ?>

                <tr id="su-post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="su-post contracten">
                    <td class="meta_data" onclick="showInfo()"><?php bedrijfsnaam(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php naam_contactpersoon(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php url(); ?></td>  
                    <td><?php start(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php eind(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php frequentie(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php datum_onderhoud(); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <div id="bedrijfsinfo-<?php echo $counter?>" class="infobox">
                    <p>Bedrijfsinformatie<br><?php bedrijfsnaam() . url() . start() . eind(); ?></p>
                    <button onclick="showInfo()"><p class="button">Sluiten</p></button>
                </div>
                <?php $counter = $counter + 1; ?>
        <?php endwhile; }

<script>

function showInfo() {
    var tr_count = document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
    for (var i = 1; i < tr_count; i++) { 
        var popup = document.getElementById("bedrijfsinfo-"+ i);
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
     }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `showInfo` function iterates over the entire number of rows. Sounds like that's not what you want. Maybe try passing in the id of the thing clicked?

```
<td class="meta_data" onclick="showInfo(<?php $counter; ?>)"><?php bedrijfsnaam(); ?></td>
// ...
<button onclick="showInfo(<?php $counter; ?>)"><p class="button">Sluiten</p></button>

function showInfo(i) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("bedrijfsinfo-"+ i);
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```